# How to get my dog to poop during the day rather than the night?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I have a 10 week old cavapoo puppy and she seems to just poop during the night. She gently wakes me up at 1 Am, 3 Am and 6 Am for poops. She usually starts at 20:00 and has 1-2 poops before sleep at around 11. She barely poops during the day and however many times I take her outside.

She gets food at 08:00, 12:00, 15:00 and 18:00, and no more food or water after 19:00.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When do you feed the puppy? That has a lot to do with when they have to go.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a few puppies recently, so I'm trying to remember if they had to go during the night, and the answer was yes, with the three of them. Sometimes to pee, sometimes to poop, but every night for a couple of weeks, then tapering off.

All puppies started out at night in a crate. I fed my pups three times a day, last meal about 18:00 as well.

Answer (score 1):

We simply shut our Labrador puppy into the kitchen overnight and cleaned up the pee and poop every morning and took it as part of the routine.

Over time, the discipline gets better and they do their business where they should do.

It would be a good idea to move the last feeding time earlier in the evening to help minimise night-time doings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you are looking for.

You need to crate her during the night, and also wait till she is five-ish months old. She won't sleep reliably through the night before.